# Dropdown in DOJO widget shows up differently in different Android devices

Tags: android, dojo, widget, ibm-mobilefirst, dropdownbox

We have issues with Dropdown control in one of our DOJO widget. In many case user is not able to select options of drop down as it appeared to be disabled. We tested in three android devices. In all three, dropdown's selection box is appearing differently ( e.g in some case with 'Done' button on top and in some other case with out that  ) . User could select the option only in one case.

Below is the DOJO widget html we used

```
<div>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props=" variableHeight:true" clickable="true" dojoAttachEvent="onClick: showList" >
    <div class="quesDetailDiv">
        <input type="hidden" dojoAttachPoint="question" value="${QUESTION}">
        <input type="hidden" id="${QUESTION}" dojoAttachPoint="${QUESTION}" value="${OPTION_SELECTED}">  ${QUESTION}
    </div>
    <div class="primaryColor selectOptionDiv" dojoAttachPoint="required">${OPTION_SELECTED}
    </div>
    <div id="selectionDiv" dojoAttachPoint="optionPt" style="display:none">
        <select class="brainQuizSelectMenu" id ="requiredId" name="select" dojoAttachPoint="requiredValue" data-dojo-attach-event="onblur : handleSelection">
            <option value ="Required" ><--select--></option>
            <option value ="Never Or Almost Never" >Never or Almost Never</option>
            <option value ="Occasionally">Occasionally</option>
            <option value ="Often">Often</option>
            <option value ="Very Often">Very Often</option>
            <option value ="Always or Almost Always">Always or Almost Always</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do we have any work around? Is this a known issue?.

Comment: Which devices? model? OS version? Worklight version? Dojo version?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard android webview in which to display HTML.

Phone vendors will instead implement the webview based on webkit version 534.30 (for android 4.0 - 4.3 at least).
This leads to differences in the behaviour and styling between webviews based on the phone you are using, the vendor and version of android. So I am not surprised they look different on different phones. There are also lots of different bugs depending on the phone model and version you are using. Luckily dojo takes care of most of these for you.

To help you further however, can you provide the phones you are using, including android version and user agent. Also it would be useful to know what js is interacting with the widget. If you can create a JS fiddle as an example, that would be great too. http://jsfiddle.net/